# "No adapter for endpoint" with class marked @XmlType as return type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, soapserver

I have problem with implementing SOAP Web service with `spring-boot`.

I have class

```
@Endpoint
public class EndpointPortTypeImpl implements EndpointPortType {
    @PayloadRoot(
            namespace = "...",
            localPart = "getReq")
    @ResponsePayload
    @Override
    public GetResp getReq(@RequestPayload GetReq parameters) {
        return new GetLinkedAcctResp();
    }
}
```

Classes `GetResp`, `GetReq` and  interface `EndpointPortType` are generated from `wsdl`.

When I try to access to this service I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [public com.mydomain.GetResp com.mydomain.EndpointPortTypeImpl.getReq(com.mydomain.GetReq)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:235)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

It happens because `XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor` can process parameters with type annotated with `@XmlType` or `@XmlRootElement`, but return value should be annotated only with `@XmlRootElement`.

My generated `GetResp` have `@XmlType` annotation so `XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor` does not support it.

For obvious reason I can't add `@XmlRootElement` to `GetResp` and I don't want to implement my own `MethodReturnValueHandler`.

How to configure spring-boot to work with return values without `@XmlRootElement` annotation?

Comment: could you share the xsd of GetResp?

Comment: Return `JAXBElement<GetResp>` instead of `GetResp` the same probably applies to your `GetReq` element which you also need to wrap in a `JAXBElement`.

Comment: @mart I don't have any `xsd`. I generate all Req/Resp classes from `wsdl`. And I can't change this `wsdl`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I should try this, but I prefer to leave signature as it is. Because I implement generated interface `EndpointPortType`.

Comment: Why on earth would you implement that interface? That interface is for use with JAX-WS not with Spring Web Services.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I implement this interface then in case of changes in `wsdl` I get compiler error. What is spring way to implement soap web-services then? I found only tutorials which don't use wsdl.

Comment: because you don't need the wsdl. As I stated the interface is only there for Jax-ws based services you don't require/need them (nor should want them!) for Spring Web Services based stuff. You shouldn't even generate them. You only need the JAXB elements not the JAX_WS generated stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't generate them. It is part of requirement. I have wsdl and have to implement web service.

Comment: You did generate the interfaces and jaxb classes. You have to create a service that handles the request you don't have to implement the interface.